# Linux equivalent of Fraps

Tags: linux, screen-capture

I want to make a demo of a 3d app I'm writing, but I don't know of any good screencasting software like it that runs on Linux. Anyone know of good alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`glc`](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/glc.html) is awesome. The only issue is that there isn't a Linux Mint package for it, which probably also means there's no Ubuntu package. At least there are [installation instructions](https://github.com/nullkey/glc/wiki/Install). (If anyone from Ubuntu/Mint are reading this, please make a `glc` package!)

I tried for a while to find a Linux Mint package which was able to record Minecraft videos, and this was the only one which worked and didn't crash every three seconds.

[Settings, capture and encoding examples.](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/7742adac9d9224f01d8efb12bc8f12bd394a0320#.bash_history)

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to do it is using VLC: http://www.wikihow.com/Screen-Capture-to-File-Using-VLC

I haven't used a lot of screen capture software, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XVidCap has also been pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg can do screencasts. I found this recipe

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1440x900 -r 10 -i :0.0 -s 1440x900 -r 10 -sameq
```

somewhere on Internet months ago and wrote it down, but I never used it since I didn't need yet to record a screencast.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried gtk-recordMyDesktop? It's awesome!

```
sudo apt-get install gtk-recordMyDesktop
```

Comment: recordMyDesktop is also available as a command-line tool and with a Qt interface, fyi.